# WiFi icon missing, unable to connect to the internet, sudo not recognised, repeatedly have to fsck to boot

Tags: ubuntu-mate, initramfs

First off I’m still new to Linux :)

Anyways, I’ve been on Ubuntu MATE 17.10 for about 2 months now and lately I’ve been seeing a common error upon startup called the initramfs error. Now this has happened about 4-5 times and each time I resolve it by a fix I found online:

```
sudo fsck -f /dev/sda7
```

Now I know I should’ve done something to figure out why I keep seeing this initramfs error but I’ve been way too busy with work and other responsibilities so anyways, this happens again yesterday but something seemed off. When I typed in my usual fix (above) it said sudo was not a recognised command lol anyways it continued to work without typing in sudo and fixed whatever errors were there and then I rebooted.

That was when I noticed the WiFi icon had disappeared, so I can’t connect to the internet. I’ve tried connecting to a hotspot via Bluetooth but that didn’t work either (I think that’s a separate Bluetooth issue cuz my laptop is really old). I should also mention that I don’t have access to an Ethernet connection.

What do I do? I desperately need to use my laptop ASAP so some urgent help would be ideal!

I have tried some fixes online where I tried to connect to a WiFi via the terminal but they haven’t worked out either.

Hoping to learn something out of this :) 
[image: Edit:]

Comment: You can connect to WiFi via NetworkManager applet manually by running `nohup nm-applet &` in terminal. It is not good, that your system needs fsck often. HDD may fail. Install S.M.A.R.T. capable program with `sudo apt-get install gsmartcontrol` and then check HDD attributes in it.

Comment: @N0rbert hey, that is for commenting and helping out. I just typed that in the terminal and what first came was: [1] 2096 and then in a new line: nohup: ignoring input and appending output to 'nohup.out' What does this mean?

Comment: It is normal, it means that process is running in background. Do you have `nm-applet` in place after running this command?

Comment: @N0rbert nope, nothing has opened or popped out..I can't remember if it's installed actually but then I'd need the internet if it isn't installed..

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version and desktop environment (GNOME, Unity, MATE)?

Comment: Ubuntu Mate on Lenovo Y410-p

Comment: 16.04 LTS or 17.10? What is the output of `lsb_release -cs`?

Comment: 17.10 and the output is: artful

Comment: You may try to use terminal version of NetworkManager to connect to the internet - `nmtui-connect`.

Comment: It says NetworkManager is not running.. lol sorry if this is annoying

Comment: It means that something is broken. Please edit your question with output of `sudo systemctl start network-manager.service; systemctl status network-manager.service`.

Comment: @N0rbert hey, I just added a screenshot. What do you think?

Comment: I have no idea. Try to test network adapter from LiveCD/DVD/USB.

Comment: Clearly the output you've posted indicates that network manager isn't starting. The possible root causes are several.

Comment: Close voters. Answered.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the way you've been working around this issue in the past, I would bet money on a failing hard drive being the culprit. At this point the damage may be too severe for a simple `fsck` to resolve. You might get some indication by [checking SMART status of the drive in question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) Passing a SMART test doesn't guarantee that a drive isn't failing but failing one is pretty definitive.